# How to rearrange files into a folder via File Explorer "non-manually"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management, files-folders

So I want to try and experiment files and folders, but I want to do it "non-manually".

And when I say *non-manually*, I mean not making a new folder and dragging the files into it. Instead, I want to use the default Windows 10 File Explorer and use some shortcut (or another method) to immediately rearrange files into a folder.

What I think is best to do is to select the files that I need to put in a folder and add it in a folder. But is there a better way?

Comment: I am not going to write an answer that describes that process.  **I don't believe this question is clear.** I don't answer questions that are unclear.  [Besides you have specifically indicated, you don't want to create a new folder and indicate the contents should be compressed.](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-ntfs-compression-windows-10)

Comment: I was actually giving you time to clarify your question. I have also been up for 18 hours so I was going to bed. This was simply the last question I viewed today.

Comment: @Ramhound That's the best I can clarify. I meant selecting files and compressing it into a folder. Is it still complicated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117846/discussion-between-mark-giraffe-and-ramhound).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "compressing it into a folder"? I can't quite get what that phrase means for you. Typically the result of compression is a file, not a folder.

Comment: @gronostaj If a folder is basically a certain chunk of files, then it would mean that "compressing files into a folder" would mean getting the files into a folder whilst not in a "manual" manner as what I specified. If you want more clarification, ask me.

Comment: When I want to get files into a folder, I create a folder and drop the files into it. There's no compression involved. So what do you mean by "compress files into a folder"? Do you actually want to compress something or is it your word for "wrapping" a bunch of files into a folder?

Comment: @gronostaj I do the same thing, but here is the thing. What if I want to select a certain bunch of my files, then I want to do some method whilst they're still selected in order to be put into a folder fast? Take note that the folder didn't exist yet until the files have been "compressed" into one. And by compression, I mean that. Select, do some method, built a folder with all its contents fast.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're not talking about any compression in the technical sense of this word. That's why me and Ramhound were confused at first. If that's indeed the case, please [edit] the question to remove this ambiguous term. "Moving files into a new folder" would be clearer than "compressing files into a folder".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117849/discussion-between-mark-giraffe-and-gronostaj).

Comment: @MarkGiraffe I have removed the "compression" from your questions because compression is the act of running files through a program or algorithm that creates an "archive" that you first have to uncompress before you can use again. It is a specific term whereas what you are seemingly wanting to do is to automatically move files into a folder. If that is not your intent then please revert the edit and [edit] yourself to clarify.

Comment: You want to write a program or script then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keyboard shortcuts!

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut selected files.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new folder.
3. Type the name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm it.
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to enter the folder.
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste previously cut files.
6. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to navigate back to parent folder.

Comment: Not what I was looking for exactly, as I already know this method, but I guess it will do. Thanks for helping me in these hard days of the work.